# Distinction of keyboard and piped file input in Java

Tags: java, inputstream, command-line-interface, stdin

I am adding a command line interface to a Java program. It receives arguments on the command line and some input from the keyboard. It displays a text message to prompt for each of the necessary keyboard inputs.

If someone redirects the `System.in` from a file, the display text should be suppressed.

My first approach is to run the following check at startup:

```
System.in.available() > 0
```

Is this reliable or is there a better way of distinction?

Comment: *"Is this reliable"* I doubt it, I frequently start typing input before the program has finished launching, which just gets buffered and delivered when it launches.

Comment: Have you tried it?  Try it first, THEN ask questions.

Comment: piping is not a feature of java, it's a feature of the console. The whole point of it is to pass input between applications without telling the applications the source of them

Comment: Yes, I worried about that. What would you recommend in this case? Live with the strange "blank" output in case of the redirection or suppress the question for quick typers?

Comment: @Jim: I've tried it. And I could not fool the test using the keyboard. But it probably depends on the computer, the operating system, the keyboard driver ...

Comment: Actually, it does not. The stdin abstraction is intended to hide the difference.  If you really must you may be able to read from the `console` device, but THAT would be OS and implementation dependent.